# Animate divs sliding diagonally in opposite directions to align horizontally (w. pic)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

I have a title (APPLES) on top of 2 lines of description (one div, ORANGES...etc.) which is on top of 1 line of tiny description (GRAPEFRUIT).

Since the title is higher than the descriptions, I want to start with them uneven, then when the user hovers over the icon (the smiley face) they cross each other diagonally so that they all become aligned.
You can see the before and after diagram in the bottom right corner of the image in purple pink and blue.

**NOTE ABOUT CODE LANGS:**

I'm using slim and compiling for the .html files
and sass for the .css/scss files

HTML/SLIM CODE:

```
div class="fruit"
    div class="fruit-p"
        div id="large"
            | 
                APPLES
        div id="medium"
            p
            |
                ORANGES & LIMES
            br
            |   PINEAPPLES
    div id="small"
        | GRAPEFRUIT

div class="icon"
    img src="sass/modules/smiley.png"
```

CSS/SCSS/SASS CODE:

```
.fruit {
height: 100%;
padding: 0 10% 0 20%;
margin:7%;
text-align: left;
} 

.fruit-p {
color: #6641f0;
font-weight: bold;
}

#large {
font-size: 111px;
}

#medium {
font-size: 27px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 40%;
}

#small {
color: #b0b0b0;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: lighter;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 40%;
}
```

I'd be more than happy to paste more code if needed.
Thanks!

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ge27gopf/

Comment: can you please upload your code to jsfiddle ? than we can give you a solution with code

Comment: added!
sorry about the pastebucket, but for some reason the paste function wasn't working when I submitted the question, so I had to paste the code elsewhere.
I'll remember to use jsfiddle instead next time though.